# Fresh macos install - kubectl outputs error message

Tags: kubernetes

On Macbook Pro, tried installing from binary with curl and then with brew.

Both installs generate an error at the end of output:

```
~ via  v7.1.23
➜ kubectl version --output=yaml
clientVersion:
  buildDate: "2019-04-19T22:12:47Z"
  compiler: gc
  gitCommit: b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290
  gitTreeState: clean
  gitVersion: v1.14.1
  goVersion: go1.12.4
  major: "1"
  minor: "14"
  platform: darwin/amd64

error: unable to parse the server version: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What is the output from the command `kubectl -v=8 version` ?

Comment: What are you running on localhost:8080? If you are missing a kubeconfig, you are maybe targeting a cluster that doesn’t exist (because it’s a web server running on your machine)...

Comment: @ChinHuang - This is the strange thing. The last line of output of every command ends with the error message.  

 am hoping  it is a trivial config related issue, I don't know much about go,  diving into kubectl source was not in my plans lol!   thanks friend, have a good one

Comment: @ChinHuang  I have added the output of `kubectl -v=8 vesrion`  to the answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is another application listening on 8080 port. By default, `kubectl` will try to connect on localhost:8080 if no `server` is passed.

If you have deployed kubernetes `apiserver` on some other machine or port, pass `--server=IP:PORT` to `kubectl`.

Comment: I was running a plethora of containers in background.  The fix was as easy as typing `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)`.  Thanks mate.

Comment: glad to help you on this