# Error messages on each command for kubectl

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, yaml, kubectl

I want to use kubernetes on an ubuntu machine for development purpose (deployment/test) where I just want to run containers. So I installed kubectl following the [kubernetes manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-linux) and when that didn't work I tried some others (native package and snap) but still get the same errors.

On each command I run I get an error, for example:

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:36:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
error: unable to parse the server version: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

or

```
kubectl get services
error: yaml: line 3: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

I don't know if it has something to do with it but the same machine is running Gitlab among other things. I haven't done any configuration on kubectl.

How can I find the source of these errors?

Answer (score 1):

There is a may possibility of running another application on same port `localhost:8080`. `8080` default used by kubectl.

for more info please have a look at this : [Fresh macos install - kubectl outputs error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55818298/fresh-macos-install-kubectl-outputs-error-message)

Comment: I was afraid that could be the case, but how to run kubectl on another port then? Where can I configure that?

Comment: @BvdVen ~/.kube/config check the file.

Comment: I don't have that file :s

Comment: but try killing that port and test

Comment: I can't stop the gitlab service on that port because it's used by multiple developers.

Comment: okay you can change the port using `kubectl --insecure-port` also have a look at this : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/controlling-access/

Comment: @OhHiMark Kind of :-) I ended up with using MicroK8s, for my development environment it's sufficient.